# Failing to create an ajax request to handelbars.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatemplate, handlebars.js

I am trying to create an AJAX request (using jQuery) for handelbars.js (an by that grasp the concept of using template.

I have this data object and ajax request:

```
var data = { users: [
  {username: { firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson" } , email: "alan@test.com" },
  {username: { firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House" } , email: "allison@test.com" },
  {username: { firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson" }, email: "ryan@test.com" }
]};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('h1template.js', function(template_text){     
        var template = Handlebars.compile(template_text);
        var html = template(data);
        $('#content').html(html);
    });
});
```

this is the content of h1template.js:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Real Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#users}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{username}}</td>
          <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{email}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/users}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Something obviously is not right because this is not working**

What is wrong?
Is it something silly I do wrong with the ajax call itself? Calling it "*.js" and not "*.php" (for example)?

(I run the file inside my localhost and when looking on the network properties the 'h1template.js' status is 304-not-modified)

Comment: Try changing template name to `h1template.html`.

Comment: what are you getting when you alert(template_text)

Comment: @AshirvadSingh the callback on the ajax doesn't get called, as the file is parsed as javascript, so jquery tries to load the contents as javascript and fails, instead of just calling the callback with the returned content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the template name is .js, it is being parsed as a javascript file. So you need to change it to either .html or .php or whatever you like.

Also in the users object, the username is an object, so in the template outputting {{username}} will only give you [object, object]. You need to change it to something like {{username.name}}

Comment: thanks for the tip to change *.js to *.html and the other tip for username.name!

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with the code and found out how to write it

the h1template.html file (instead of *.js"):

```
<table>
...
</table>
```

and the script in main page is:

```
var data = { users: [
      {username: { firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson" } , email: "alan@test.com" },
      {username: { firstName: "Allison", lastName: "House" } , email: "allison@test.com" },
      {username: { firstName: "Ryan", lastName: "Carson" }, email: "ryan@test.com" }
    ]};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('h1template.html', function(template_text){   
        var source   = template_text;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data);
        $('#content').html(html);
    });
});
```